# Namespaced subdomain controllers and custom layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, namespaces, subdomain

I namespaced my subdomain and now I am trying to load custom layout for that subdomain. How can I accomplish that without using this inside my `app/controllers/student/base_controller.rb`:

```
class Student::BaseController < ApplicationController
  layout 'student'
end
```

I tried to copy my `application.html.erb` file inside `app/views/student/layouts` but I've read that doesn't work so I copied it inside `app/views/layouts/student/` and it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

When calling method `layout` you pass name of the layout file, not its directory. So in your case layout should be `app/views/layouts/student.html.erb`. Read more about layouts here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think layouts are confined by namespace

--

Here is some live code we use:

```
class Admin::ApplicationController < InheritedResources::Base

    #Layout
    layout "admin"

    ...
```

This gives us the ability to call `app/views/layouts/admin.html.erb`